# Div elements won't align next to each other

Tags: html, css

Here is what I want to get:

[image]
and here is what I have:
[image]

Here is CSS code that I am using:

```
#pagewrap {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
#board{
    //middle box
    background:#CCC;
    border:#999 1px solid;
    width: 560px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%; 
}

#menu {
    //Left box
    width: 15%;
    background-color: grey;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;

}
#leaderboard {
    //right box
    width: 15%;
    float: right;
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

**EDIT1: Added jsfiddle**

[jsfiddle.net/Xn3u6/](http://jsfiddle.net/Xn3u6/)

Comment: Create a jsfiddle.net - I suggest you make sure the container is wide enough

Comment: width is 100% @mplungjan so I think that container is wide enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve the desire result and using `display:table` and `display:table-cell` is one of the easiest way.

CHECK The **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cudosazi/1)** First.

```
#pagewrap {
padding: 5px;
width: 100%;
margin: 20px auto;
display:table;
}
#board{
padding: 5px;
background-color:#cccccc;
display:table-cell;
}
#menu {
padding: 5px;
background-color: red;
display:table-cell;
}
#leaderboard {
padding: 5px;
display:table-cell;
background-color: green;
}
```

Using [flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) also can achieve the same effect but its not widely supported by IE8 and IE9.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/judenoro/1/edit)** using `Flex Method`.

```
#pagewrap
{display:flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
width:100%;
}
#board{
padding: 5px;
background-color:#cccccc;
width:25%;
}
#menu {
padding: 5px;
background-color: red;
width:50%;
}
#leaderboard {
padding: 5px;
background-color: green;
width:25%;
}
```

Comment: Your code is @Kheema Padey working but is there any way to shrink left and right div and expand middle div

Comment: ofcouse you can..just add the `width` on desire div

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SNAG12/Xn3u6/2/
. I would suggest % width in all three cases . code:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div{
    display:inline-block;
    height:30px;
}
#pagewrap {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;

}
#board{

        background:#CCC;
        border:#999 1px solid;
        width: 70%;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px 15px;

        padding-left: 20%;
        padding-right: 20%; 
    }

#menu {
    width: 15%;
    background-color: grey;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;

}
#leaderboard {
    width: 15%;
    float: right;
    background-color: grey;
   padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xn3u6/4/)

```
   #board{
        background:#CCC;
        border:#999 1px solid;
        width: 560px; /* change this to percentage to be fluid*/
        float: left;
        padding: 4px 15px;
    }

   #menu {
      width: 15%;
      background-color: grey;
      float: left;
      padding: 5px 15px;
   }
  #leaderboard {
     width: 15%;
     float: left;
     background-color: grey;
     padding: 5px 15px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Man! You really have to learn CSS and the CSS box model:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model

I also updated your fiddle, so you get an idea, what will work. Basically I added `box-sizing: border-box;` and removed the `margin`, so the width of the boxes are fitting. http://jsfiddle.net/Xn3u6/5/